# Difference between IExceptionHandler and Exception Handling Middleware in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net-8.0, exceptionhandler

I'm seeking clarification on the difference between utilizing **IExceptionHandler** and **exception handling middleware** in ASP.NET Core. When I use **IExceptionHandler**, the handler captures the exception, but the error still appears on the console:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request`

However, when I implement exception handling middleware through a Request Delegate, no error logs are displayed on the console. I'm unsure whether this behavior is due to a misconfiguration on my part or if it's inherent to the **IExceptionHandler** approach. Could someone please provide insight into this issue?